# Schumann's grand sonata op 11: interpretation of pianissimo

Tags: piano, dynamics

The final bar of the introduction of Schumann's grand sonata op. 11 in F# minor has a `pp` stacked below the two final whole notes in the bass stave:

[image]

How should this dynamic indication be interpreted with respect to the final two-lined C# in the treble stave? Should the C# in the treble inherit the fortissimo from the previous treble notes or should the C# also be played pianissimo? I think it would be obvious that it should be pianissimo if the `pp` had been put between the staves as for the previous `ff` sign, but since the `pp` is put below the bass stave, it makes me more unsure.

Comment: What the heck's the time signature? 20/?

Comment: @Tim The introduction is 3/4, but this is just a cadenza at the end of it.

Comment: @Richard - and how does one 'play' the 'paused rest' at the end? Raising the hands majestically, I suppose.

Comment: @Tim As noted, this cadenza is at the end of the *introduction* to the sonata. The rest is necessary.

Comment: @KyleStrand - *Now* it makes sense. But I've seen similar at the end of pieces...

Comment: @Tim Fair enough! I was going to defend it on the basis of Schumann being a 23-year-old German Romantic, but realized that was unnecessary.

Comment: With regard to the time signature (3/4) vs. this cadenza measure (m.54), the latest (2009) Henle urtext notes for one of the sources--Schumann's personal copy of the First Edition, Leipzig (1836)--"...bar lines drawn by hand with lead pencil; they subdivide the eighth-note triplets into four measure."

Answer (score 3):

I'd play the bass notes pp and the treble ff. There seems no other reason for placing the pp at the bass. It looks like a kind of echo effect.

Answer (score 3):

I think the notation is clear.  Schumann was fond of experimenting with pianistic "effects".

Here's a performance that ignores the ff.  (And which, to my mind distorts the melody by applying excessive rubato and hammering out the accompanying arpeggios.  A prime example of a classical pianist refusing to let music have any simplicity and overdoing the "expression". Compare many performances of Beethoven's "Moonlight" movement.)

Kissin has a better awareness of the melody, and follows Schumann's dynamics as written.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting viewpoints and the videos.  So if I interpret you correctly, the C# in the treble should be played `ff`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes, and I'd agree. Note that the notes of the lower register tend to last longer when let ring than the notes in the upper register, so I think Schumann was expecting that the audience might not even hear the bottom note until somewhat after the attack.

Answer (score 1):

pp in the left, ff in the right.
Listen to Andras Schiff. There is also a masterclass with him on this movement.